# Is it possible from dataframe transform to Matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, multiple-columns

I am newbie in python,
I have a huge `dataframe`:

```
Person  OD
A       BS1
A       BS2
B       BS4
B       BS8
C       BS5
C       BS1
D       BS9
D       BS7
E       BS2
E       BS7
F       BS2
F       BS1
G       BS1
G       BS2
```

is it possible to transform into an origin-destination (OD) matrix in python-pandas? Example from BS1 to BS2 there is 2 person (A and G) then in OD matrix 2 people into BS1-BS2.

my expected result:

```
O/D BS1 BS2 BS3 BS4 BS5 BS6 BS7 BS8 BS9
BS1     2                           
BS2 1                       1       
BS3                                 
BS4                             1   
BS5 1                               
BS6                                 
BS7                                 
BS8                                 
BS9                         1
```

how to do it? thanks a lot

Comment: Do the input data always have two consecutive rows for each person and the first is the origin?

Comment: yes, it does, and the data always pair.. the first line is the origin and the second line is the destination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is a solution.

```
places = df["OD"].unique()
places.sort()
od_df = pd.DataFrame(df["OD"].values.reshape((-1, 2)), columns=["O", "D"])
od_matrix = od_df.groupby(["O", "D"]).size().unstack().reindex(index=places, columns=places)
od_matrix.fillna(0, downcast="infer", inplace=True)
```

You can also use `pd.pivot_table` and replace the fourth line with

```
od_matrix = pd.pivot_table(od_df, index="O", columns="D", aggfunc="size").reindex(index=places, columns=places)
```