# OD Matrix with freq data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on this post:
[OD Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520616/is-it-possible-from-dataframe-transform-to-matrix)

I have huge dataframe. I want to make an OD matrix. However, I have a frequency column data. The data  looks like this:

```
print (df)

O   D   Freq
A   B   1
A   C   2
A   D   3
B   A   1
B   C   1
C   A   2
C   B   1
C   D   1
D   C   2
```

My desire output looks like this:

```
print (Dfnew)

O/D A   B   C   D
 A  0   1   2   3
 B  1   0   1   0
 C  2   1   0   1
 D  0   0   2   0
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: I think you need pivoting.

Comment: Forgive me @jezrael, Iam not good in python. Which kind of pivot that I can use for my data?

Comment: I think here should be used `df = df.set_index(['O','D'])['Freq'].unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: thank @jezrael, you're the best.. I will learn again about pivoting.